# Python. Regular expression

Tags: python, regex

How to find everything which goes after symols `#TR=`  and it is inside `[ ]` using re module.  For example `#TR=[ dfgg dfgddfg  dgfgf dgdgdg dfgfg ]`

Comment: Are you expecting nested `[ ]` inside your top level of `[ ]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
txt = '#TR=[ dfgg ] a kuku #TR=[ala ma kota]'
```

If you want to search for just the first occurrence of this pattern, use:

```
matches = re.search('#TR=\[([^\]]*)\]', txt)
if matches:
    print(repr(matches.group(1)))
' dfgg dfg '
```

If you want to find all occurrences in the text, use:

```
matches = re.findall('#TR=\[([^\]]*)\]', txt)
if matches:
    print(matches)
[' dfgg ', 'ala ma kota']
```

Remember to check whether the characters you are searching for have [special meaning](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in regular expressions (like `[` or `]`). If they are special, escape them with the backslash: `\[`.

Also remember, that by default, regular expressions are "greedy" which means they try to get as much text to match the pattern as possible; so if you use `.*` (which means "match any character except newline"; [details](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)) instead of `[^\]]*` (which means "match until the `]` is found, and stop before it"), too much text could be matched:

```
matches = re.findall('#TR=\[(.*)\]', txt)
if matches:
    print(matches)
[' dfgg ] a kuku #TR=[ala ma kota']
```

You can also use the "non-greedy" modifier `?` in your pattern, after the qualifier (`*`, `+`) which enables the "the-less-characters-the-better" matching (use `*?`, `+?`). The result could be more readable:

```
'#TR=\[(.*?)\]'
```

instead of:

```
'#TR=\[([^\]]*)\]'
```

There's a great online tool to test your patterns as-you-type: [RegExr by Grant Skinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
# compile the regex
exp = re.compile('.*\[(.*)\].*')
txt = r"#TR=[ dfgg dfgddfg dgfgf dgdgdg dfgfg ]"
match = exp.match(txt)
# grab the text between the square brackets
result = match.group(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited your answer by mistake, meant to edit my own. Reverted my change.

Answer (score 0):

(?<=#TR=[)[^]]*(?=])